# Filter VCF file for most differentiated SNPs (Fst) in VCFTools

Tags: snp, filtering, genetics

I have a filtered VCF file that I want to subset for the 500 most differentiated SNPs based on estimated Fst values (calculated in vcftools). I am not completely sure how to approach this. I have calculated the fst values across all populations (10 in total), but am not sure how to specify that I only want 500 SNPs with the highest fst value.

I used VCFTools, but would BCFTools be more appropriate?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example we can use, and the output you would want from that example. We cannot help you filter data we cannot see. Show us a valid VCF file (that means all headers plus a few variant lines) and then tell us which variants you want to keep from it.